# Little Group of massive particles in moving frame

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, group-theory, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

My understanding of the little group till now was, that we take some standard-momentum and define the little Group as the subgroup of the Poincaré group that leaves this standard-momentum invariant. E.g. for massive particles, we can go to the rest frame and then define the little group as not to alter $(m,0,0,0)$, which results in $SO(3)$ being the little group. This can then be used to get unitary irreps of the Poincaré group by first transforming to the rest frame, letting $SO(3)$ act on the state and then apply the remaining boost and translation.

In all of this, the little group was always defined only for the rest-frame momentum.
I now started reading Schwartz's book on QFT, where in Chapter 8 he takes a look at Spin-1 particles. Talking about the little group for these particles he states:

> For the massive case, the little group, holding for example $p = (m, 0, 0, 0)$ fixed (**or any other 4-vector of mass m**), is just the group of three-dimensional rotations, $SO(3)$.

I don't see, how $SO(3)$ can be the little group for an arbitrary 4-momentum of mass $m$.

Edit:
Later, on page 125 he goes on to say

> The group that fixes $p^μ = (E, 0, 0, p_z)$ is also SO(3), although it is harder to see.

I, again, cannot see how this can be true.

Comment: Under any 3D spatial rotation, the zero 3-vector is mapped to itself independent of the mass. The little group is the set of ALL transformations that leave the momentum unchanged. The result immediately follows.

Comment: I agree with everything you said, but isn't Schwartz stating something more general? He says that any 4-vector of mass m, i.e. any p with $p^2 = m^2$ will be unchanged by SO(3) which makes absolutely no sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any 4-vector $p^\mu$ of mass $m$ can be obtained from the reference momentum $k^\mu = (m,0,0,0)$ via a Lorentz transformation $L(p)$ so that
$$
p = L(p) k. 
$$
Let $W$ be an element of $SO(3)$ which preserves $k$, i.e.
$$
W k = k .
$$
Then,
$$
W(p) \equiv L(p) W L(p)^{-1}
$$
preserves $p$ since
$$
W(p) p = L(p) W L(p)^{-1} p = L(p) W k = L(p) k = p.
$$
Additionally, the set of all $W(p)$ forms the group $SO(3)$ since the set of $W$'s forms the group $SO(3)$ and $W$ and $W(p)$ are related by a similarity transform (which of course corresponds to a change of basis).

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thanks for taking the time!